# How to properly rotate MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm having some issues properly rotating an instance of MPMoviePlayerController. I want it to rotate based on iPad orientation. Normally, it works. Sometimes, however, something strange happens, and then it's screwed until I restart the program.

Here's my initialization code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Drew 320x240" ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:nil];
myMPC = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

[[myMPC view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 597, 448)];
myMPC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(SP_D2R(-90));
myMPC.view.center = CGPointMake(364, (850 / 2) + 168);
```

Here's my orientation code:

```
    -(void)orientationDetected:(UIEvent *)event{
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        if (myMPC) {
            myMPC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(SP_D2R(90));
            myMPC.view.center = CGPointMake(405, (850 / 2));
        }
    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        if (myMPC) {
            myMPC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(SP_D2R(-90));
            myMPC.view.center = CGPointMake(364, (850 / 2) + 174);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are some screenshots. The first two are how they're supposed to be (one with the home button left, and the other with the home button right), the third one is the screw up. Here they are:

[image: Landscape Home Button Left]

[image: Landscape Home Button Right]

[image: Screw Up]

As you can see, the video of the boy moves out of position and leaves blackness where it should have been (although the black rectangle isn't exactly where it should have been anyway -- it should be more to the left in that example). Once this happens, all subsequent device rotations result in this (until the program is restarted).

This is not a simulator-specific issue, as this happens on the actual iPad. Again, sometimes it rotates fine. Is there something I'm missing/does anyone know why this is happening/does anyone know how to prevent this?

I appreciate the help.

Thank you,
Ilya

EDIT: Initialization code added and pictures are now embedded.

Comment: try setting the frame again with every rotation

Comment: I just tried setting it right before and then right after -- it's a no go. Thanks anyway. Any more ideas?!

Comment: I did the same as Shaharyar pointed out...MPMoviePlayerViewController in combination with presentModalViewController:animated:

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues when I used `MPMoviePlayerController` the first time. The orientation just didn't work for me.

What I found was: [`MPMoviePlayerViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html) (It contains a `MPMoviePlayerControlle`)

Using this new class, I had no more issues with the orientation. I was also able to define my own orientations in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` by subclassing it. (Felt like magic :P)

Bear in mind that the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class is called by `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:(MPMoviePlayerViewController)]`

Managing the orientation the way you're doing it right now is very tedious and error prone.

It can be done much easier using the built in classes in the framework.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I would have responded sooner but I didn't get an email notification... oh, well.

I just want to make sure I understand your answer correctly: I should subclass MPMoviePlayerViewController, and then add the method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to my new class? Is there anything I'm missing? Does my new class need to receive orientation notifications?

Thank you,
Ilya

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned - you just override the shoulAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in your new subclass and add your supported orientations to it.

Comment: Okay. I'll try this and get back to you.

Thank you,
Ilya

Comment: Shaharyar, was your movie playing in fullscreen mode? I'm not sure your method will work because I need the movie to be in a very specific location on screen and my movie is not being played in fullscreen mode.

Comment: shoot, yes. my movie is playing in fullscreen mode. - I will have a look into it and let you know

Comment: Ah, bummer. I updated my question with a little more code detail. Thanks again!

Ilya

Answer (score 0):

I think setting an anchor point around which the video will rotate might solve your issues.

Try to init as follows:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Drew 320x240" ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:nil];
myMPC = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

[[myMPC view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 597, 448)];
[[myMPC view].layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake( 0.5, 0.5 )]; // center of your view
```

The video should now rotate around its center.

You can find more details in [the Apple Docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082)